# Application Insights Instrumentation Key not working using path declared in .json

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

In my service fabric stateless project, I have three .json files namely:

1. appsettings.json
2. appsettings.development.json
3. eventFlowConfig.json

These files are under the WebAPI project. The last file: eventFlowConfig.json contains a line:

```
"type": "ApplicationInsights",
"Instrumentation Key": "servicefabric: /AppInsights/InstrumentationKey"
```

In the Service project, in ApplicationManifest.xml, the Instrumentation Key is declared in a section:

```
<section name="AppInsights">
   <Parameter name="InstrumentationKey" value="[Instrumentation Key]">
</section>
```

This service project has a file DevelopmentEnv.xml where the actual Instrumentation key is kept.

When I run the project, the application insights is not working and no trace is logged. However, when I hardcode the Instrumentation Key in eventFlowConfig.json, instead of the path shown above, it starts working.

I want to pick from the path as shown above. Can the instrumentation key be fetched using the above path or it is mandatory to hardcode the key instead of the path.